# Moving to Australia after Bachelor's

Tags: visa, immigration, australia, student-visa

I have a 4 year bachelor's degree in Software Engineering from a university in England. I also have one year of internship experience working in a software company.

I am planning on moving to Australia and doing a Masters degree in a software related field, using `Higher Education Sector visa (subclass 573)`. Most masters degrees are 2 to 4 years long, part time. I understand that I can work part time in Australia once my course commences. After my course finishes, I'll hopefully be working in Australia and will be able to apply for `Skilled—Recognised Graduate visa (subclass 476)` or `Skilled Regional (Provisional) visa (subclass 489)` and later on apply for PR.

My end goal is to get a related job and settle down in Australia. My question is, is this approach correct. If not, I'll have to work in my current country for a few years (gaining experience) and then apply for migration through a job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get points based on your age, diploma, work experience and IELTS exam score (You can also get points for certificates and such)...

Most points you will get for age, then for diploma, then IELTS, then experience...

Points for age:

```
18-24 (inclusive)   25
25-32 (inclusive)   30
33-39 (inclusive)   25
40-44 (inclusive)   15
45-49 (inclusive)   0
```

Points for IELTS (you need min 6 to apply):

```
All 8 . 20
All 7 . 10
All 6 . 0
```

Points for diploma:

```
Doctor. 20
At least a Bachelor degree. 15
Diploma or trade qualification. 10
```

Points for work:

```
At least eight and up to 10 years (of past 10 years).   15
At least five but less than eight years (of past 10 years). 10
At least three but less than five years (of past 10 years). 5
```

Here [you can find more info on points](http://www.visabureau.com/australia/immigration-points-test.aspx)

Comment: Based on your answer, are you suggesting that I try applying for skilled migration? (Instead of moving for an MSc or something similar)?

Comment: @john Hi John, If you can get enough points then absolutely.... based on your end goal... I mean assuming you are 28~. 30pts + ielts(7) 10 pts+ diploma 15pts + 5pts sponsorship from state (visa subclass 490) = 60 (add certificate if uncertain 5pts) = 65.

Comment: I appreciate your info. However I am ~21 years old, with around 1.5 years of work experience. So my score would be `25` + `20` (I am confident I can get an 8) + `15` (degree) = `60`. Without the 3 years of work exp, am I even eligible?

Comment: @john 8 ielts heh,... but yeah you need 3 years min, sorry...